# Rigol DS2072A with compensated PVP2350 probes has overshoot at 100 mV/div. Bad?

Tags: oscilloscope

With my new DS2072A I compensated the PVP2350 probes according to the instructions at 50 mV/div as chosen by the "Auto" button. Then, when I switch to 100 mV/div there's some overshoot with both probes on both channels.

[image: Test signal at 50 mv/div]

[image: Overshoot at 100 mv/div]

It's more obivous at 2 ms/div:
[image: 50 mV/div, 2 ms/div]

[image: 100 mV/div, 2 ms/div]

- Is that bad?
- Is there anything I can do to fix it?
- Is it a fault of the scope or the probes?
- Could it be a factory reject smuggled out of the factory and sold by crooks?

I bought it from taobao.com  via superbuy.com (a taobao agent who orders from taobao who only ship to China and forwarded it to Austria), so I'm not sure what my warranty options are.

I unlocked the scope to 300 MHz and ran self calibration.
Software version: 00.03.06
Hardware version: 2.3

Comment: The scope is not properly compensated./calibrated. The rest, who smuggled the scope and what about warranty is up to you.

Comment: Then how do I properly compensate/calibrate it? The instructions say to turn the slit till the wave is square, which I did. When I switched to 100 mV/div it overshoots. BTW, it wasn't smuggled, I declared the real value and paid import tax and fee.

Comment: @darsie, get your story straight ... you are the one that said `smuggled out of the factory`

Comment: @jsotola Ahh, right, forgot about that.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if the answer form Rigol should make me sad or happy:

On 8/14/19 9:46 AM, Seber.Yang@rigol.com wrote:

> Dear Sir
>
> Nice to meet you!
>
> After confirmed, it's normal phenomenon, and it don't affect the
>   performance of the oscilloscope, thanks~

Comment: You can adjust the compensation of the probes using any voltage setting you like.  If you need nice, flat tops at 2mV per division then adjust the compensation at that setting.

Comment: @JRE Yeah, I just considered that a tedious workaround rather than normal.

Comment: You'd love my old D43 then.  Pretty much any change of setting means chasing around and readjusting other things.